# se puede guardar un datos del datagrid sin tener que usar una base de datos

Tags: c#

Me han pedido hacer este proyecto usando colas, pero mi problema es que quisiera saber si se puede guardar datos del datagridview en la memoria sin tener que acudir a un programa de base de datos.

[image: [1]]

Comment: ¿Guardarlo para qué motivos? Poder usarlo dentro de la ejecución de tu script, seguro en un arreglo, mientras este exista cuando tu código se ejecuta, si quieres guardarlo para después usarlo, además de bases de datos puedes usar archivos de texto que guarden la información, por poner un ejemplo de muchos otros.

Comment: pero se puede hacer eso? guardar momentaneamente solo cuando esta en ejecucion? precisamente eso quiero solo para cuando esta en ejecucion tuvieras algun codigo si me pudieras ayudar por fabor

Comment: Jose Miguel: antes de nada, es importante saber exponer bien. [He editado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74564/revisions) tu publicación para intentar darle cierta coherencia. Tu formación no debe ser solo en informática, sino en comunicación. Esto lo necesitarás toda la vida y no solo laboralmente, por lo que es bueno que le prestes más atención.

Comment: hay que saber algo, no quieres ocupar base de datos o te pidieron que no fuera con base de datos? Si se necesita "guardar" o hacer persistencia de esos datos lo mas facil seria utilizar algun motor de base de datos. Si no es asi, lo normal es un `List` y que hagas "persistencia" de esos datos mientras el programa se ejecute tal como te lo dicen los demas

Comment: si se puede :v no estas preguntando como, asi que solo te digo que si se puede ;)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas,

Entiendo que lo que quieres guardar en memoria son objetos de tipo Cliente.
Suponiendo que tienes una clase cliente con este aspecto:

```
public class Cliente
{
    private int codigo;
    private string nombre;
    private string apellidos;
    private string dni;
    private int telefono;
    private string direccion;

    ...

}
```

Puedes almacenar objetos de esta clase en una cola  tendría esta pinta:

```
 Queue<Cliente> colaClientes = new Queue<Cliente>();
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Primera aclaración: durante la ejecución de una aplicación las variable se mantienen persistente en memoria (a menos que se liberen sea por el alcance "scope" o por Dispose). Por lo que puedes agregar y quitar elementos de tu datagrid y permanecerán durante la ejecución.

Dicho esto otra opción de entre tantas es persistir en un archivo.
En este ejemplo serializo una lista de clientes en un archivo xml. Espero que te sirva de referencia.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SerializacionConsola
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Creo un cliente
        Cliente chapulin = new Cliente()
        {
            Nombre = "Chapulin",
            Apellido = "Colorado",
            Codigo = 123
        };

        List<Cliente> cartera = new List<Cliente>();
        cartera.Add(chapulin);

        //Almaceno el listado en un archivo XML.
        string pathArchivo = "./carteraClientes.xml";
        Guardar(cartera, pathArchivo);

        //Obtengo los datos que se almacenaron en el archivo.
        var registrados = Obtener(pathArchivo);

        //Los muestro por pantalla
        foreach (Cliente item in registrados)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Codigo + " : " + item.Nombre + " " + item.Apellido);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene los datos desde el archivo XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Ruta al archivo XML</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static List<Cliente> Obtener(string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path", "el path al archivo xml no puede ser nulo o vacio");

        List<Cliente> listado = null;
        //Deserialize
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cliente>));
            listado = (List<Cliente>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return listado;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Almacena los datos en un archivo xml.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lista">Origen de datos</param>
    /// <param name="path">Ruta al archvio XML</param>
    static void Guardar(List<Cliente> lista, string path)
    {
        if (lista == null || lista.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("listado", "El listado de clientes no puede ser nulo o vacio.");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path", "El path al archivo xml no puede ser nulo o vacio");

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cliente>));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, lista);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Entidad que representa al cliente
/// </summary>
public class Cliente
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
}
```