# Deserealizar lista objetos C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

Estoy tratando de armar un programa simple para practicar lo visto en la facultad, es algo de archivos xml.
El programa esta hecho en windows forms, y necesito lograr que me guarde objetos de mi propia clase, pero tengo un problema cuando intento deserealizar, el archivo esta serializado en otra parte del programa, y creo que esta bien, el archivo esta creado pero no logro cargar los datos en mi lista de objetos.

```
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            Resumen resumen = new Resumen(); //Lista de mi clase donde guardo los objetos.

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 f = new Form2(resumen); //le paso la lista donde guardar objetos al formulario que guarda los datos en el xml
                f.Show();
            }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Cuenta c = new Cuenta();

                            XmlSerializer serializador = new XmlSerializer(resumen.GetType());
                            FileStream archivo = new FileStream("D:\\Resumendecuenta.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     //el archivo lo busco en "D:\\.." aunque originalmente no lo guarde ahi  cuando serializo, 
    //copie el archivo y lo pegue manualmente ahi.

                            resumen = (Resumen)serializador.Deserialize(archivo);  //<-- Aca es donde tengo el error! me dice invalidOperationExeption.
//Información adicional: Error en el documento XML (13, 13). (eso dice)

                            archivo.Close();

                            //r += c;

                            richTextBox1.Text = resumen.Mostrar();
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido un error", "Error en el archivo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
```

esta es la otra parte donde guardo y genero el xml.

```
Resumen resumen = new Resumen();
        public Form2(Resumen r)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            resumen = r;
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    DialogResult result; //Variable para guardar una seleccion de MessageBox.

                    //do
                    //{

                        Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta(textBox1.Text, float.Parse(textBox2.Text)); //creo una cuenta con sus respectivos valores.

                        //resumen += cuenta; //agrego una cuenta al resumen.
                        resumen.resumen.Add(cuenta);

                        FileStream archivo = new FileStream("Resumendecuenta.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); //creo un archivo xml.

                            XmlSerializer serializable = new XmlSerializer(resumen.GetType()); //creo el serializador.
                            serializable.Serialize(archivo, resumen); //serializo

                        archivo.Close(); //cierro el xml

                        //Muestro mensaje de creacion exitosa y capturo la seleccion.
                        result = MessageBox.Show("Cuenta guardada exitosamente! ¿Desea guardar otra cuenta?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

                        //Limpio los textBox para ingresar nuevamente datos.
                        if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
                            textBox1.Clear();
                            textBox2.Clear();
                        }
                    //} while (result != DialogResult.No); //Se repite mientras el usuario seleccione 'Si'.

                    Close(); //cierro el formulario.
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ups! Se ha producido un error", "Formato Invalido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```

Mi consulta es basicamente si estoy deserealizando bien, me da el error invalidOperationExeption Información adicional: Error en el documento XML (13, 13). cuando intento mostrar los datos deseralizados que intento guardar en la lista con objetos de mi clase

Cuenta y Resumen son dos clases propias, Resumen solo tiene la List y Cuenta tiene dos atributos, nombre y monto, con sus respectivos get y set (en propiedades).
Las pequeñas partes de codigo comentadas son de cosas que quize agregar pero no logre la funcionalidad adecuada, solo importa lo que esta sin comentar.

Comment: Prueba sin espacios en las url's Utiliza guiones bajos, o todo junto

Comment: el segundo error parece una derivacion del primero (que es que no encuentras el archivo, encontra el archivo primero!)

Comment: Eh movido el archivo y eh cambiado su nombre "D:\\Resumendecuentas.xml" y aun asi sigo teniedo problemas.

Comment: @LucasMedina Cuando dices sigo teniendo problemas ¿te refieres a que te sigue dando la excepción FileNotFound u otra distinta?

Comment: Por cierto en el código que se crea el fichero se le da el nombre `Resumendecuenta.xml` pero al leerlo se busca `Resumendecuentas.xml`  no sera por la `s` final verdad?

Comment: jaja, era eso ! muchas gracias, vi 300 veces el codigo y no me di cuenta de eso, muchas gracias! ya esta solucionado

Comment: ¿Y el tema de la `s` final?

Comment: era eso, el tema de la S, me pasa por no prestar atencion, gracias!

Comment: @Gerardo, ahora tengo problemas cuando intento deserealizar, me da la exepcion no controlada invalidoperatorexeption, sabrias porque es ?

Comment: Podes utilizar esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74712/30418
Aqui tenes un ejemplo de como serializar en un archivo xml una lista de una clase cliente

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable sea que o estes haciendo mal la referencia al archivo o esté siendo utilizado por algun proceso.

Aquí te dejo mi versión de consola pero utilizando tu código como referencia.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace ErrorSerializacion
    {
        public class Program
        {
            private static string rutaArchivoXML = @".\Resumendecuenta.xml";

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                GenerarXML();

                ObtenerXML();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public static void ObtenerXML()
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***** ObtenerXML:");

                    Resumen resumen = new Resumen();

                    XmlSerializer serializador = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resumen));
                    FileStream archivo = new FileStream(rutaArchivoXML, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    resumen = (Resumen)serializador.Deserialize(archivo);

                    archivo.Close();

                    if (resumen != null && resumen.Listado != null && resumen.Listado.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(resumen.Listado[0].Cadena + " - " + resumen.Listado[0].Flotante);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("resumen vacio o nulo.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                }
            }

            public static void GenerarXML()
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***** GenerarXML:");
                    Resumen resumen = new Resumen();
                    Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta("una cuenta", float.Parse("2")); //creo una cuenta con sus respectivos valores.
                    resumen.Listado.Add(cuenta);

                    FileStream archivo = new FileStream(rutaArchivoXML, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); //creo un archivo xml.

                    XmlSerializer serializable = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resumen)); //creo el serializador.
                    serializable.Serialize(archivo, resumen); //serializo

                    archivo.Close(); //cierro el xml

                    //Muestro mensaje de creacion exitosa y capturo la seleccion.
                    Console.WriteLine("Cuenta guardada exitosamente!");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exc.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Resumen
        {
            private List<Cuenta> _listado;

            public List<Cuenta> Listado
            {
                get
                {
                    return _listado;
                }
                set
                {
                    _listado = value;
                }
            }

            public Resumen()
            {
                this._listado = new List<Cuenta>();
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Cuenta
        {

            public string Cadena { get; set; }
            public float Flotante { get; set; }

            public Cuenta()
            {
                this.Cadena = string.Empty;
                this.Flotante = 0f;
            }

            public Cuenta(string p1, float p2)
            {
                // TODO: Complete member initialization
                this.Cadena = p1;
                this.Flotante = p2;
            }
        }
    }
```